# Automatically reload an iframe if source page changes

Tags: javascript, iframe, automation, reload, detect

I don't know what's wrong with my code, even if I change the content of the target file it still wont refresh the iframe.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var page = 'data/apps/<? echo $_SESSION['name']; ?><? echo $_SESSION['last']; ?>App.html', lM;

function checkModified(){
   $.get(page, function(a,a,x){
      var mod = x.getResponseHeader('last-modified');
      if(lM != mod){
         lM = mod;
         document.getElementById("frame").src += "";
      }
   }
}

setInterval(checkModified, 5000); // every 5 seconds
</script>
```

What I want to achieve is when there are changes on the target page, the iframe will automatically reload itself so that the changes can be shown to the user. Both pages are located in the same domain.

Comment: What do you mean by target page? The page that contains the iframe or the page that is within the iframe?

Comment: Ah, I see - you mean the page within the iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you had a missing closing bracket ")" at the end of the `$.get` method.

The main problem, though, was probably that your server is not sending proper `Last-Modified` headers. The server I tested on didn't send any, meaning `mod` is undefined. A workaround is to check for `Content-Length` instead. It's not ideal because an edited page doesn't necessarily change size, but it seems you're in control of the page so you could ensure you add an extra byte to force a refresh.

Here is your `checkModified` function updated which should work:

```
function checkModified() {
   $.get(page, function(a, b, x) {
      var mod = (x.getResponseHeader('Last-Modified')) ? x.getResponseHeader('Last-Modified') : x.getResponseHeader('Content-Length');
      if (lM != mod) {
         lM = mod;
         console.log('Fetched');
         document.getElementById("frame").src += "";
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: Just want to check the easy things first: you're editing several bytes (not just changing a single character) and you're hosting it on a server rather than file://localhost?

Comment: working when it's only this "x.getResponseHeader('Content-Length');"

Comment: problem now is the cache, cause when the page cache sets it sometimes messes up the acquiring of the exact size of the file.